# Firefox fails to render SVG in IMG tag

Tags: html, svg

I am attempting to add an SVG image to an HTML file. I have index.html and star.svg together in a directory. Firefox 96 on Ubuntu fails to render the image, only shows alternate text. I also tried with an OBJECT tag, but just prints source of star.svg.

star.svg displays properly everywhere else.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

The HTML and SVG I am using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SVG Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="star.svg" alt="star" height="210px" width="500px">
    <object data="star.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try to add attriutes `version` and `xmlns` to your svg tag like this: `<svg version="1.1" height="210" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

Comment: @BaroI will add that as an answer if noone else answers.Thanks much.

Comment: @RobertLongson Will you please elaborate. If I add the namespace attribute as suggested by Baro to my SVG  tag,  my SVG is rendered in my Firefox as desired. Is this an error?

Comment: Without a namespace I'd be surprised it works in any browser. I.e. all browsers should work the same and all should demand a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to include the `xmlns`:

```
 <svg height="210" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg):

> The xmlns attribute is (…) required on the outermost svg element of SVG documents. (…)